# Ocean: Creating surface from another surface

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I like to create a new `Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Shapes.Surface` from `Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Shapes.Surface` by performing calculations on every points on the surface to generate a new surface, any idea how it can be done?

Comment: This is highly specialized software from Slumberger and you're probably going to have to go to them directly for support, good luck, I've worked with them in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to `RegularHeightFieldSurface` instead of `Surface`, which is abstract. You can do something like the following:

`var outSurface = parentCollection.CreateRegularHeightFieldSurface("output surface", inputSurface.SpatialLattice);`

You can then iterate through all `Samples` of the inputSurface, compute your output samples, and set outputSurface.Samples to the computed samples.

As an alternative, instead of creating a new surface, you can just create a new `SurfaceProperty` of the input surface.

Comment: No, I want to create a new surface from an existing surface just like we do it by seismic calculator